# Transition tab not visible -JIRA Suite Utilities Plugin

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have installed the JIRA Suite Utilities plugin (Version:
1.4.10) in my JIRA server instance (version 6.4) and I need to tracking the time taken for each workflow transition.but i cant see the transition tab in the issues. I have followed the [plugin documentation](https://jsutil.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JSUTIL/JIRA+Suite+Utilities+Documentation) also.
am I missing something?

I have posted this question in [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/15301576/transition-tab-not-visible--jira-suite-utilities-plugin) also and searched for answers in atlassian answers under "addon-com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities" tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I missed.In default the transition tab module and most of the modules  were disabled in the plugin. then i had to enable it manually.